# Multiple users using a spreadsheet at the same time, but it can only be used one at a time. What to do?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the Session.getEffectiveUser () command to return the results of the active user in the worksheet, but if another user enters the same sheet the results will conflict.

That is, only one can enter at a time. What can I do to keep this conflict from appearing?

Crazy solution that I thought: Is there any way that this worksheet doubles if I have 2 active users at the same time, and delete if that second user leaves?

Thx a lot!
And sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Yup, the solution you thought is totally crazy. What if there are thousands of users in future? Maintaining all those with 6 min of time out rule of appscript is gonna be hell of a tedious task. One thing you can do is create your project using html, javascript and appscript combined and deploy it as web app. Hence, your `Session.getEffectiveUser()` or `Session.getActiveUser()` will work and also there won't be any conflicts as everyone will be running the code as you. Hope you know what I'm talking about, else I can explain you in detail in answer.

Comment: Thx @ShyamKansagra for answer!!

Yeah, I know.. ;/

I know what you're talking about, I just do not know how to run .. haha

Would you have any way to do it simply and practically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to deploy your code as a web app so that conflicts won't happen.

1. For this, you will need a front end where you will take inputs or whatever from the current user who will be accessing the web app.
2. Now, in your appscript screen only, you can go to File -> new -> html file, and name it as index.html or whatever you like. Code it in simple html format. Apply javascript also if you have to. For adding javascript externally, you can create another .html file and write your  tag there. These all is simple html and javascript only.
3. Now, we have to link it with our appscript somehow. So for that, write this function in your appscipt:

   ```
   function doGet(e) 
   {
       var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');  

       return template.evaluate()
       .setTitle('YOUR_TITLE')
       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
     }
   ```

And also write this line in your Index.html page(You can write it outside of `<html>` tags):

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

4. Now your code is ready to be deployed as web app. Go to Publish -> Deploy as web app...See that you have kept the option 'me' in Execute app as. Also, you can specify who can access your web app in the next option 'who has access to this app'.
5. Click update and run the latest code by clicking 'latest code' written in blue. You can also note it's URL so that you can include your web app in google sites etc.

Note that, every time you make new changes to the code, you should always choose project version 'new' and then click update.

Few tips:
To call functions of appscript from javascript, you can write like this:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(FUNCTION_NAME).APPSCRIPT_FUNCTION();
```

What it will do is, it will asynchronously call appscript function and when it is successfully executed, will execute the next javascript function named 'FUNCTION_NAME'.

How this will solve your problem?

- Well, as you have deplyed the web app as 'me', whoever will run the web app will execute the code as if you yourself has executed the code, but at the same time, all featuers like `Session.getActiveUser()` will work individually. Hence, conflicts won't happen.
  Try this yourself and you will have your doubts solved. If any queries please ask, community is always happy to help. :)

Comment: thx man! That should work!

But, I have another problem:
Some users would have to make a change in some data, and not only visualize them, is this possible?

Comment: Yup, that is also possible. What I suggest is: Maintain a spreadsheet type of database so that you can use it as lookup. e.g. make a sheet with 2 columns, i.e. user's email and his row in which he is allowed to change data. Now, whenever a user uses your web app to fill the data, refer that sheet and get that row in `sheet.getRange(row, column)` and overwrite the new data. If you think there are any issues in this, please tell. There are lot of workarounds, I suggested the first which came to mind.